# Asterisk, DID incoming call trouble

Tags: asterisk

We are working with Asterisk and we have some problems to receive call using DID numbers. 
When we are calling the did number Asterisk do not see the incoming calls. Nothing happens. 
We have checked on the voip server and we get the calls but Asterisk is not taking the calls.

Please find below the conf files:

`Extensions.conf`:

```
[general]
static=yes
writeprotect=no
autofallthrough=yes
clearglobalvars=no
priorityjumping=no

[globals]
CONSOLE=Console/dsp
IAXINFO=guest
TRUNK=Zap/g2
TRUNKMSD=1 

[ovh_sip] 
;exten => s,1,Ringing(1) 
exten => s,2,Answer 
exten => s,3,Dial(SIP/201,30) 
e    xten => s,4,Hangup(16) 

[outgoing_calls]
exten => _X.,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN:1}@forfait-ovh)

SIP.conf
[general]
context=forfait-ovh
bindport=5060
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
srvlookup=yes
register => login:password@sip5.5voip.be
registerattempts=0
registertimeout=3600

[201]
type=friend
username=201
callerid="201" <3223315331>
secret=201
host=dynamic
context=appel_sortant
language=fr
insecure=port
nat=yes
canreinvite=no
dtmfmode=auto
video=no
restrictcid=no
amaflags=default
mailbox=201@mondomaine.com

[202]
type=friend
username=202
callerid="202" <3223315331>
secret=202
host=dynamic
context=appel_sortant
language=fr
insecure=port
nat=yes
canreinvite=no
dtmfmode=auto
video=no
restrictcid=no
amaflags=default
mailbox=202@mondomaine.com

[forfait-ovh]
type=peer
host=sip5.5voip.be
context=ovh_sip
language=fr
insecure=port,invite
username=3223315331
secret=5telecom
nat=yes
canreinvite=no
dtmfmode=auto
video=no
restrictcid=no
amaflags=default
```

The sip account is not registered all the time , when we type "show sip registry" it  is always empty.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "qualify=yes" to your SIP trunk options for [forfait-ovh] above, and (as payne says) turn on SIP debugging.

In addition, just to be sure: you say you're familiar with VoIP so perhaps this is a dumb suggestion, but ...

I guess your Asterisk server is behind a firewall right? So I imagine that you've done all the sensible and necessary steps to allow an *externally* originated call to be delivered to your Asterisk box, by setting up the necessary port forwarding rules on your router/firewall?

There is an overview here: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/port+forwarding
and also here: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/679361

In fact there are loads of such things ...

Answer (score 0):

If Asterisk is not registered with your VOIP provider, then your VOIP provider won't send any calls to you.  That's the whole point of registration; it's in effect saying, "I'm here to take calls!"

I'd figure out why you are not registering.  Double check your login and password information.  Make sure you don't have a firewall or router in the middle that's preventing registration.  Ask your VOIP provider if they have any debugging information they can share with you on registration attempts.  Turn on Asterisk verbose logging ('core set verbose 100') and see if you are getting any useful messages regarding registration failures.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The login & password are correct because we can make calls with the VOIP provider. I think that the problem is that asterisk is not connected all the time on the VOIP server only when we make calls. If I want to receive calls , I need to keep alive the connection between asterisk & the voip supplier. Do you know how I can fix a keep alive connection between Asterisk and VOIP Server ? Thank you

Comment: What type of Internet connection is it?

Comment: The internet connection is dynamic. But the DID is configured on the VOIP Server and Asterisk has to be connected to the VOIP Server to receive the call. Otherwise, when the voip Server is sending the call to the SIP account , the sip account is offline and the call is missed. We are a company who provides VOIP calls through our VOIP SERVER, we worked with VOXBONE for the DID. The DID is mapped to the SIP account. Thank you for your help

Comment: If the connection is "dynamic", then I'd focus there on keeping your internet connection up.  You might be able to work with your ISP, or configure something in your modem or router.  OR, set up a "ping" that keeps the connection up.  OR, configure the SIP timeout in Asterisk to be something like 30 seconds.